# How to get child record type Name in SOQL

Tags: soql, custom-object, record-type, relationships, object

I am trying to query and get the record type of the child record of a Parent record.

I amusing the below code but I in the result of record name I get [Object Object] only. Why does the name of the record type is not displayed

Query:

```
select id,Chil_relationshipName__r.Name,Chil_relationshipName__r.RecordType.Name from parentObject__c
```

In the record type column I get - `[Object Object]` instead of the name of the record type.

Comment: Found the dupe. Minor variations on this question have been asked many times already on SFSE.

Comment: Also your syntax indicates it's a parent record, *not* a child.

Comment: You are right! my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how the developer console displays results when you traverse more than one level of relationship. If you want to see the results, you have to use a different tool, such as `Apex`. For example, you'd see the values using `Execute Anonymous`:

```
for (MyObject__c record : [/*query*/])
{
    system.debug(record.Parent__r.Grandparent__r.Field__c);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hope when I use the recordtype.name in an apex code it would not show [object object]

Comment: No, `Apex` will not suffer any such limitation.